# Bootstrap nested row margin top/bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build an application that has a metro interface.
Rows are stacked like columns and the children are tiled.

in bootstrap **rows** have a margin-left of -15px and the same for the right. I have then added 15px padding to the **.row**. My columns then have a margin of 15px all around. So, I have to make my margin-top: -15px and the padding-top: 15px on my row (aswell as the bottom).
All this should give me exactly 30px between every column and row. The problem is when I nest, it all goes to pot.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.metro {
  width: 10000px;
}

.metro .row-title {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  top: -50px;
}

.metro > .row {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 630px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.metro > .row .row {
  padding: 0;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-1 {
  width: 75px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-2 {
  width: 150px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-3 {
  width: 225px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-5 {
  width: 375px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-6 {
  width: 450px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-7 {
  width: 525px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-8 {
  width: 600px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-9 {
  width: 675px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-10 {
  width: 750px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-11 {
  width: 825px;
}

.metro > .row > .col-md-12 {
  width: 900px;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* Safari */

  display: flex;
  /*> div {
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            flex-basis: auto;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }*/
}

.flex.flex-wrap {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex.flex-vertical {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row div[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

[class*="col-"] > div:not(.row):not(.alert),
[class*="col-"] > a,
[class*="col-"] > form {
  display: block;
  background-color: #3C60EF;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] > div:not(.row):not(.alert) .form-group:last-child,
[class*="col-"] > a .form-group:last-child,
[class*="col-"] > form .form-group:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

and the HTML that is messing up is this:

```
<div class="container metro">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 row-title">
      <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row flex flex-vertical">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="box-shadow">
                <p>
                  Some welcome text
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div>
                    <p>Nesting</p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div>
                        <p>Nesting</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="box-shadow">
                <p>Disclaimer</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <form class="col-md-12" name="loginForm" role="form">
          <div class="box-shadow">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Enter Username" required="" ng-model="controller.user.userName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required="" ng-model="controller.user.password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="controller.loginUser()">Login</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div>
                <p>Another nested row</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a codepen where you can see my issue:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/ojNVeX

does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Besides your problem, whats the point in using the Bootstrap grid classes with absolute sizes? Furthermore, Bootstrap rows are rows, not columns. Don't try to stack them as columns. Use columns instead, they were made to, you know, act like columns. ;)

Comment: Trust me when I tell you that using the columns as columns causes many issues when you go to lower resolutions. I have replied to your answer so you should know a bit more about how I have my site structured. The only thing I need to work out is the padding / margin in nested rows. After that, everything else will be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I managed to do this myself](http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/epYoMZ)

Basically I just started with the default bootstrap and then played around until I got my desired results.

Here is the CSS that I changed:

```
.metro > .row {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.metro > .row .row {
  background-color: orange;
}

.metro > .row .row .row {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.row div[class*="col-"] {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.row [class*="col-"] > div:not(.row),
.row [class*="col-"] > form,
.row [class*="col-"] > a {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

There was no need to add anything else, this solved all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want to create a metro-style UI. Here's a snippet which could be the base for this. As I mentioned in a comment above, do not use bootstrap rows as columns.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.metro {
  width: 10000px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.metro .page {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  float: left;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

.content-login  {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.content-page2 {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="metro">

  <div class="page">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div class="row content content-login">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="page">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <div class="row content content-page2">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for your answer, but I already have the UI in place. I am using bootstrap because I want it to only be in Metro when above 1200px. Below that it can show as a normal bootstrap site.